# Showing that if a function is $O(x^2)$, then it's also $o(x)$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

How to prove the relationship above? The big $O$ and small $o$ are used in the context of $x\to 0$.

I've been told the proof goes like that:
If $|f(x)|<cx^2 $ (that's the property $f(x)=O(x^2)$, then of course also $\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}<c|x|$ is arbitrarily small when $x\to 0$ (meaning $f(x)=o(x)$.

Could anyone explain why? How to prove it rigorously? What I see above is the fact that both sides of inequality were divided by a number, and that operation doesn't change the direction of inequality. But I'm not sure if it's rigorous enough.

Would $O(x^2)$ imply $o(x)$ if I'd chosen a different limit than $x\to 0$, for instance $x\to a$ for some positive $a$? I guess not, because $c |x|$ doesn't get arbitrarily small in this inequality $\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}<c|x|$ (if it did, that would mean $f(x)$ is $o(x)$.

Comment: It is since you divide both sides by a positive number. It   uses only the elementary rules on inequalities.

Comment: That's a perfectly rigorous proof, provided you understand what your're talking about.

Comment: I understand it like this: for every $c$ there exists $X$ sufficiently close to $0$ such that for every $x: 0<x<X$ the inequality is true. So we in fact have uncountably many such inequalities and divide every such inequality by a positive number $|x|$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bernard does it make sense or not really?

Comment: Your understanding is not quite correct: the exact formulation is there exists constants $c, X>0$ such that the inequality is true for every $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert<X$. In particuler, it is not ‘for every $c$’.

Comment: @Bernard Oh, yeah, right. Sorry. What about the rest (i.e. uncountably many such inequalities, etc.)

Comment: Why, yes, if it is valid for a$c$ and some $X$, it is also valid for all $X'\ge X$. But it doesn't seem to be the point here.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $f \in O(x^2)$ for $x\to 0$ means that in some neighbourhood of $0$ for some constant $C$ it holds: $|f(x)| < C x^2$. While $f\in o(x)$ means that $f(x)/x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. So, if $f\in O(x^2)$ you have
$$
\left |\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| \le C |x|
$$
in a neighbourhood of $0$. Remember now that the limit of a function in a point only depends on the values of the faction in any neighbourhood of the point. So the limit on the left exists and is equal to $0$ since the limit on the right is zero (comparison principle).

Comment: Okay, but if $f=O(x^2)$, then $|\frac{f(x)}{x}|\le C|x|$ is true for some constant $C$, not every positive $C$. If we want $f=o(x)$, then the following inequality must hold for every $M$: $|\frac{f(x)}{x}|\le M$, no matter how small $M$ is. I think I get your point: $M$ is $C|x|$ in this case, so as $x$ gets closer to $0$, $M$ gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: Whatever is $C$ one has that $C|x|\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that (last sentence of my comment).

Comment: If I'd chosen a different limit (not $x\to 0$, but $x \to a$ instead for some positive $a$) then $O(x^2)$ wouldn't imply $o(x)$ anymore, right?

Comment: For $x \to a\neq 0$ you have $O(x^2) = O(1)$ and $o(x) = o(1)$. And yes, they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Taking  following definitions for $a$ point:
$$O(g) = \left\lbrace f:\exists C > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x( |x-a|<0) (|f(x)| \leqslant C \cdot |g(x)|) \right\rbrace$$
$$o(g) = \left\lbrace f:\exists \epsilon(x), \lim_{x \to a}\epsilon(x)=0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x( |x-a|<0) (f(x) = \epsilon (x) \cdot g(x)) \right\rbrace$$

So, both are sets and first gives some "intellectual" boundary for its $f$ elements, while second gives some kind of representation for its $f$ elements in $a$'s neighbourhood. Main relationship is:
$$o(g) \subset O(g), x \to a.$$
Proof: let's take $\phi \in o(g)$, then $\exists \epsilon(x)$ and neighbourhood $U(a)$ of $a$ in which $f(x) = \epsilon (x) \cdot g(x)$. As $\lim_{x \to a}\epsilon(x)=0$ then we can find some neighbourhood $V(a)$ in which $|\epsilon(x)| \leqslant C$, for any $C>0$. In intersection $U(a) \cap V(a)$ there will be $|f(x)| \leqslant C \cdot |g(x)|$, which finishes $\phi \in O(g)$.

Now we can consider $a=0$ and show $$O(x^2) \subset o(x), x \to 0.$$
Proof: let's take $\phi \in O(x^2)$, then we know $|\phi(x)| \leqslant C \cdot |x|^2$ for some $C>0$ and in some neighbourhood $U(0)$. Taking representation $\phi(x) = x \cdot \frac{\phi(x)}{x} = x \cdot \epsilon (x)$ for $x \in U(0) \setminus \{ 0 \}$, we obtain $\phi \in o(x)$.